# name 'self' is not defined when running "Tutorial.objects.all()" in cmd

Tags: python, django

I am trying to do the webapp project using django

here's the code in the `model.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Tutorial(models.Model):
    tutorial_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tutorial_content = models.TextField()
    tutorial_published = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):       
        return self.tutorial_title
```

When running `Tutorial.objects.all()` in the cmd, it return errors "name `self` is not defined"

Comment: Are you importing `Tutorial` from your `models.py` before running the command?

Comment: Yes, I have done "from main.models import Tutorial" in the cmd, and shows "<QuerySet []> at first.

Comment: But after I did                                                                                                       
>>> new_tutorial=Tutorial(tutorial_title="To Be", tutorial_content="...never mind", tutorial_published=timezone.now())
>>> new_tutorial.save()                                                                                        >>> Tutorial.objects.all()                                                                                             It shows" NameError: name 'self' is not defined "

Comment: Did you override the `save()` method?

Comment: No I didn't override the save(), but what do i need to do to override the save()? Thank you!